# How to use Launchctl for schedule application

Tags: mojave, catalina, launchd

I try to work with `Launchctl` and have a question:

How can I set up an application to run in a few minutes using `Launchctl`? (for example, open the program MyApp.app with arguments "hello" "world" Every 10 minutes)

I know that it can easily be done by creating `Launch Agent`, I looking for a way to do it using `Launchctl` directly to programmatically.

Comment: If you know how to do it with LaunchAgent, why do you want to do it the complicated way? What is the problem you are trying to solve here?

Answer (score 1):

`launchctl` is for loading, manipulating and unloading LaunchAgents and LaunchDaemons, it doesn't directly support delayed execution. What you can do instead is

- Run `sleep $((10 * 60)); launchctl submit -l my_choosen_name mkdir /tmp/mydir`
- Run `launchctl submit -l my_name -- bash -c 'sleep 6$((10 * 60)) && mkdir /tmp/mydir'`
- Have your LaunchDaemon plist call a script (instead of the application directly) and include the `sleep` in the script before it starts the application

To have it run every 10 minutes use

```
while sleep $((10 * 60)); do
    launchctl submit -l my_choosen_name -- myapp hello world
done
```

Comment: It does not help with periodic task or tasks that need to start in a specific time and date

Comment: @parkjoh Also, for periodic tasks or tasks with a specific time/date, use either `cron` or a LaunchAgent. Doing this the hard way isn't useful.

Comment: Why not just use `sleep 600` instead of `sleep $((10 * 60))`?

Comment: @user3439894 I had to answer the question about how to change the sleep duration too often in the past :-)